# Update statistic counter or just count(*) - Perfomance

Tags: mysql, optimization, count, statistics, sql-update

What is the faster/better way to keep track on statistical data in a message board?

-> number of posts/topics

Update a column like 'number_of_posts' for each incoming post or after a post gets deleted.

Or just count(*) on the posts matching a topicId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `count(*)` - it's built into the database. It's well tested, and already written.

Having a special column to do this for you means you need to write the code to manage it, keep it in sync with the actual value (on adds and deletes). Why make more work for yourself?

Comment: Sometimes I'm thinking complicated. While writing the code i did not know that count(*) does not really count over every record if there is an index. Now i have a system that does this on it's own and updates the counters. But now i know that updating with every action is very bad. But i just wanted to be sure before I cahnge everything.